# Remove class when a div is not clicked (onclick not true)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I am writing a small JQuery/JS code to create some interaction in my application. I am working with a div that will be a different color if I click on it. Than, if I click on it again (It checks of the div has the class that will provide the color), it will pop up a modal. But, now, I would like to remove the color if I click anything but the div. So, The div is grey, when I click on it it will become yellow and than after I click on something else it must turn grey again. I thought something like if the div got the class `"clicked"` and the click is not true on the div, it will remove the class `"clicked"` My code:

```
$(".progressDefault").click(function(){
  if ($( ".progressDefault" ).hasClass( "clicked" )) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  }
  if ($ (".progressDefault").hasClass("clicked") && $(".progressDefault").onclick == false ) {
    $('.progressDefault').removeClass('clicked');
  }
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

HTML Div

```
<div class="progress-bar progressDefault" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25"` aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 25%;">
  <span class="sr-only">25%</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Add the relevant HTML code please.

Comment: Done, this is the specific div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For removing `clicked` class you need to attach click handler on document and check for `e.target`

```js
$(".progressDefault").click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass( "clicked" )) {
       alert('show modal');
    }else{
      $(this).addClass('clicked');
    }
  });
$(document).click(function(e){
  if(!$('.progressDefault').is(e.target) && $('.progressDefault').has(e.target).length === 0){// if div is not target nor its descendant
    $('.progressDefault').removeClass('clicked');
  }
});
```

```css
.progressDefault{
  border:1px solid black;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  padding:10px;
  background:grey;
}
.clicked{
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='progressDefault'>test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to check click outside of your desired document..

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $(".progressDefault");
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    /* if the target of the click isn't the container && nor a descendant of the container */
        $('.progressDefault').removeClass('clicked');
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/m9c771LL/76/)